# php send mail issue

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I am developing a web application (Php+Apache+Postgres on Ubuntu) where registered users can send emails to the admin and vice versa. I have sendmail installed as MTA. The problem is php mail command isnt sending/receiving any mail. The registered users can have any email id e.g. user1@abc.com, user2@xyz.com and admin can be admin@example.com.

I earlier tried ssmtp MTA but using that if i provide admin's email (e.g. gmail's authentication), then admin can contact users but I could not figure out the other way around communication (from users to admin because it is not necessary that all users have gmail id).

Can you guys throw some light on how to solve this problem such that any user with any email id an contact the admin or vice versa. What would be the best steps to address this problem? Currently I am using a localhost.
Thanks for your support.

**Edit:** The sending of emails is facilitated using  a form with to,subject, message fields

Comment: The php `mail` command only takes care to hand the email message over to the MTA. If the MTA is not working, your email would not be send. Check your MTA setup. Next to that the php `mail` command will never take care of receiving mail messages.

Comment: @Treffynnon: Well users cannot communicate among themselves but admin. And admin can see user's emails.

Comment: @hakre: If this web application is hosted on real server then how would in and out flow of emails will happens such that mails sent using this application are delivered to the desired recipient's inboxes?

Comment: @Shehroz: Naturally this is controlled by the configuration of that server. The sysadmin of that server should be able to give you the info you're looking for.

Comment: @hakre: Actually its not recieving and sending its sending only. Admin can send emails to users (and they should receive in their inbox) and users can send email to admin (who will receive in his inbox)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching from sendmail to postfix? Postfix is usually a better alternative to sending mails.

Here's a [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix) to installing Postfix on Ubuntu.

Comment: I was reading these alternatives of postfix, exim etc. Do you think postfix can address the problem I am seeking for?

Comment: Yes, I've had  multiple problems with sendmail, one of them being that the emails were not sent (were stuck in the queue). It was all resolved after switching to postfix.